# Solr EmbeddedSolrServer in solr5+?

Tags: solr

it's been a long time since I last use Solr (4.1), and I noticed that with the new version 5.2, there is no EmbeddedSolrServer. I used the following code to create a local server (without an http server) in 4.1, is it still possible in 5.2?

```
File configFile = new File(cacheFolder + File.separator + "solr.xml");
CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(cacheFolder,
         configFile);
SolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "collection1");
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its possible you can check here

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html

But I would suggest not to go with embedded one , see the below link

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr